# Create directory structure

Tags: c#

Is there any way I can create a list with all the folders and files that are in a directory? I will specify the path and I want to list all its child folders and files, and write them in a txt file, or maybe an xml file to make it easier to read.

Comment: Well which bit are you stuck on? See the `Directory` class for methods to fetch the content of a directory.

Comment: If you just want a file with the data, use `dir` or `ls`.

Comment: I'm stuck on how to see which folder is the parent for others. I can get all the folders and files, but I was thinking that I need a structure that will help me determine which folder is in which folder(for example a tree).

Answer (score 2):

The [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method should give you a list of all files, along with their full paths:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetFiles` and `Directory.GetDirectories` methods should help

Answer (score 0):

This is a good link to get all files:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/

And to get all directories: use Directories.GetFolders() instead.

Then you have to make a for loop or something to traverse them them.
Perhaps a recursive method would be a good selection. Something like
void PrintFilesAndFolders(string directory)...